# How can I make another row appear inside of another row in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a header image with some text located at the bottom of the image. Every time I create the row and columns though, the text just goes to another line. The problem is that I am trying to create a header image that has two instances of text. I have messed with absolute position and that is not working either. I have also tried messing with d-flex properties, align-items-end, and justify content...

I know this is an easy fix, I am just trying to figure out how to make the text appear at the bottom.

So how would you create the image below for an example?

[Header Image](https://imgur.com/a/MGJG0Qz)

```
<div class="fluid-container" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="row" style="">
    <div class="col"> <img class="card-img-top" src="images/electrical-repair.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""/>
      <h4 class="text-danger d-flex justify-content-center bannerText text-center">Premiere Commercial Electrical Services in the Northwest</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that combines some custom code and bootstrap. You may need to resize or show in full screen view, hope this helps.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.full-home {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-position: 50% 50%\9 !important;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.hero-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero-wrapper-inner {
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.hero-wrapper-bottom {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="full-home" style="background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800');"></div>
<div class="hero-wrapper">
  <div class="container hero-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-wrapper-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```